# this.prop is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery code is:

```
$('#edit').click(function(){
    var data = $("#list :input").serialize();
    $.post($("#list").attr('action'), data, function(json) 
    {
        currentRow = json.rowArr[0];
        $("#id").val(currentRow.id);
        $("#id_disp").val(currentRow.id);
        $("#shop").val(currentRow.shop);
        $("#category").val(currentRow.category);
        $("#item").val(currentRow.item);
        $("#qnty").val(currentRow.qnty);
        $("#unit").val(currentRow.unit);

        $.each($("#price_based_on").children('option'), function(index, val) {
            if(this.value.toUpperCase()==currentRow.price_based_on.toUpperCase())
            {
                console.log("Match");
                this.prop("selected", true);
            }
        });

        $("#mrp").val(currentRow.mrp);
        $("#sellers_price").val(currentRow.sellers_price);
        $("#last_updated_on").val(currentRow.last_updated_on);

    },"json");
});
```

Among this, the only thing of interest are the lines:

```
$.each($("#price_based_on").children('option'), function(index, val) {
    if(this.value.toUpperCase()==currentRow.price_based_on.toUpperCase())
    {
        console.log("Match");
        this.prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

On using the statement `this.prop("selected", true);` I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.prop is not a function

Why does this happen when .prop() is clearly a function that exists? How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to make `this` to a jQuery object.. `$(this).prop` should work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$.each` is used to iterate over an object or array. If you want to iterate over the nodes in a `jQuery` object, use `.each` like this:

```
$("#price_based_on").children('option').each(function() {
     ... code here
});
```

Inside the call back, `this` refers to the native `DOM` element (which doesn't have a `prop` method, so you probably want to do something like this to get a reference to the `jQuery` object that holds the `DOM` node:

```
$("#price_based_on").children('option').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop('selected',true)
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`this` is not a jquery object, you need to add jquery selector `$()` around to make it jquery object, so change it to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a jQuery object. Use `$(this)`

```
$(this).prop("selected", true);
```